# Error handling for Firestore transaction in Flutter

Tags: flutter, error-handling, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter and trying to make an app in which I need to run a transaction. In case the transaction fails I need to inform the user. I tried using catchError but it didn't work. I am using latest cloud_firestore from pub. So how can I catch the error?